# MyBatis spring in a multi tenant application

Tags: spring, ibatis, multi-tenant, mybatis

Hi needed some help in using MyBatis spring in a multi tenant 
application ...

Is it possible ? Especially since i do not see how 
"MapperScannerConfigurer" can be configured with sqlSessionFactory at 
run time.

Comment: Why don't you use jpa? It's so powerful.

Comment: Yes I agree, JPA is powerfull, However i am creating a CQRS style application, and use JPA for the write and MyBatis for the read side.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out? My team is facing the same challenge. We have hundreds of identical databases that we might need to connect to from a single application and we don't know which until runtime based on the request context.

Comment: I think I have :), I have written about my approach [here](http://noobjuggler.blogspot.in/2012/03/multitenant-mode-for-dddcqrs-base.html), I am basically making use of the [AbstractRoutingDataSource](http://blog.springsource.org/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach using a plugin (a.k.a. interceptor) to switch 'schema' or 'catalog'.

Depending on the database you use, each tenant has its own database or schema.
A few examples:

- MySQL : Each tenant has its own 'database' and the plugin should call `setCatalog`.
- Oracle : Each tenant has its own 'schema' and the plugin should call `setSchema`.
- SQL Server : Each tenant has its own 'database' and the plugin should call `setCatalog`.

Assuming you pass the tenant ID via ThreadLocal, here is an example plugin implementation.

```java
import java.sql.Connection;

import org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.StatementHandler;
import org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Interceptor;
import org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Intercepts;
import org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Invocation;
import org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Signature;

@Intercepts(
  @Signature(
    type = StatementHandler.class,
    method = "prepare",
    args = { Connection.class, Integer.class }))
public class MultiTenantInterceptor implements Interceptor {
  @Override
  public Object intercept(Invocation invocation) throws Throwable {
    Object[] args = invocation.getArgs();
    Connection con = (Connection) args[0];
    con.setSchema(TenantIdHolder.getTenantId());
    // con.setCatalog(TenantIdHolder.getTenantId());
    return invocation.proceed();
  }
}
```

`TenantIdHolder` is just a `ThreadLocal` holder.

```java
public class TenantIdHolder {
  private static ThreadLocal<String> value = new ThreadLocal<>();

  public static void setTenantId(String tenantId) {
    value.set(tenantId);
  }

  public static String getTenantId() {
    return value.get();
  }
}
```

Here is a [demo](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-9430294) using HSQLDB.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create tenant scoped datasource using factory and wire it to SqlSessionFactory which is used by mappers generated by mybatis-spring. Here is relevant app-context.xml section

```
<bean id="dataSourceFactory" class="com.myapp.TenantDataSourceFactory"
      depends-on="tenant" scope="singleton"/>

<bean id="dataSource" factory-bean="dataSourceFactory" factory-method="getObject"
      destroy-method="close" scope="tenant" >
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>

<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:myBatisConfig.xml" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="com.myapp" />
    <property name="annotationClass" value="com.myapp.mapper.Mapper"/>
    <property name="sqlSessionFactoryBeanName" value="sqlSessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

And TenantDataSourceFactory:

```
public class TenantDataSourceFactory {

@Autowired Tenant tenant;

  public DataSource getObject() throws Exception {
    BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
    ds.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    ds.setUrl(String.format("jdbc:postgresql://%s:%s/%s",
            tenant.getDbHost(), tenant.getDbPort(), tenant.getDbName()));
    ds.setUsername(tenant.getDbUser());
    ds.setPassword(tenant.getDbPassword());
    return ds;
  }

}
```

`tenant` scope is custom scope that holds `Map<String, Map<String, Object>>` that is tenant name to scope beans map. It dispatches to given tenant based on notion of *current* tenant.

Comment: Where does the tenant scope (`scope="tenant"`) come from?

Comment: It is custom scope implementation, I've added some details.

Answer (score 0):

Spring has AbstractRoutingDataSource to take care of this problem

http://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/