# Switch Schema based on call from rest controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jersey, mybatis

We have two products: Product A and Product B and both have different rest controllers. Both of these controllers are calling the same common service and the common service calling the common dao methods. I want to select the schema in the common daos methods based on which products the call has been made. So for example, if the call is coming from the **Product A controller** then select schema as **A** or else **B**.

I wanted to use the same database connection and change the schema based on which controller the call is made. One possible solution would be to pass the schema name from the controller layer to the service layer which in turn passes it to the dao layer. I want to avoid having two different data sources and then switching between them dynamically.

So is there any other better way that we could do this?

Note: We are using Mybatis as our persistence layer.

Please find the sample code :

**Controller for ProductA**

```
@Component
public class ProductA{

    private final CommonService commonService;

    public ProductA(CommonService commonService){

            this.commonService = commonService;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/test/dbSchema")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getTotalProducts(){
        // Calling common service method here to get total products

    }
}
```

**Controller for ProductB**

```
@Component
public class ProductB{
     private final CommonService commonService;

    public ProductA(CommonService commonService){

            this.commonService = commonService;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/test/dbSchema")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getTotalProducts(){
        // Calling common service method here to get total products

    }
}
```

FYI: We are using Jersey

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60789865/1261766) is an example that switch 'schema' or 'catalog' using MyBatis' plugin (a.k.a. interceptor). You might have to use something other than `ThreadLocal` to store the 'key' if your app uses single-thread model.

Comment: @ave we have to define this ThreadLocal at the controller layer for each product? Is there a way we can decide in the common service layer?

Comment: Please add the code of both controllers. Then I'll try to show you how to use the `ThreadLocal`.

Comment: @ave Added the code by editing the question above.

Comment: Can they have the same `@Path` value? Anyway, using the classes posted in the linked answer, you call `TenantIdHolder.setTenantId("schema_a")` in `ProductA#getTotalProducts()` and call `TenantIdHolder.setTenantId("schema_b")` in `ProductB#getTotalProducts()` (you need to change the schema names, of course). `setTenantId()` is a static method, so you can call it directly from your controllers. If you are not familiar with `ThreadLocal`, see the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @ave for the response. I am able to solve it by using ThreadLocal as you mentioned. By setting the tenant id in the controller, I am able to get the particular tenant in the common service.

Please find the updated code below:

**Controller for Product A**

```
    @Component
    public class ProductA{
    
        private final CommonService commonService;
    
        public ProductA(CommonService commonService){
    
                this.commonService = commonService;
        }
        public void setSchema(){
        TenantContext.setCurrentTenant("ProductA");}
@GET
        @Path("/test/dbSchema")
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Response getTotalProducts(){
             setSchema();
            // Calling common service method here to get total products
    }}
```

**Controller for Product B**

```
 @Component
    public class ProductB{
         private final CommonService commonService;
    
        public ProductA(CommonService commonService){
    
                this.commonService = commonService;
        }
        public void setSchema(){
            TenantContext.setCurrentTenant("ProductA");}
    
        @GET
        @Path("/test/dbSchema")
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Response getTotalProducts(){
        setSchema();
            // Calling common service method here to get total products
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please add the correct code with the solution to your answer please?

Comment: @Yonlif Done. Added the correct code with solution.