# Choose schema name dynamically in mybatis xml based on request attribute

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis

How to dynamically pick the schema name based on a request in my batis schema?

We would like to do this without changing the arguments or definitions of Mapper files or with parameterType as this requires changes across code

Is it possible to use lookupKey from datasourceRouter in mybatis xml file ?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60789865/1261766) might help.

Comment: @Ave This answer helps only to choose database instance dynamically but not the schema name in the mysql queries.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. In MySQL, ["a schema is synonymous with a database"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_schema).