# How can I avoid Mybatis reloading configuration for every `SqlSessionTemplate`?

Tags: spring, mybatis, spring-mybatis

Recently I noticed that my project takes quite a long time initializing Mybatis-related beans and classes. My database has tens of shards and there is a wrapper that routes queries to the shards. After some research, I found out that inside the wrapper each shard holds a separate `SqlSessionTemplate`, and every time it is created and initialized, it loads Mybatis configuration and mappers. Each load takes less than a second but it sums to several tens of seconds.

Since all session templates are exactly the same except for their data sources, I don't want the load happens every time the session template is initialized. So I registered the Mybatis configuration as a bean and injected it into each `SqlSessionFactoryBean` as follows:

```java
SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
sqlSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
sqlSessionFactoryBean.setConfiguration(configuration);
```

But all the sql sessions ended up sharing the same data source, since the data source was being stored in the `Configuration`, whose singleton bean was shared across all the `SqlSessionFactoryBean`s.

I searched for a way to clone the `Configuration` object without reloading all the configs, but couldn't find any.

If you have any idea how to instantiate several `SqlSessionTemplate`s without reloading the Mybatis configs and mappers every time, whether it reuses `Configuration` or `SqlSessionFactoryBean`, please let me know.

Versions: Spring 4.3, Mybatis 3.4, Mybatis-spring 1.3

Comment: Have you considered using [`AbstractRoutingDataSource`](https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing)? It is also possible to [switch catalog/schema](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60789865/1261766) using MyBatis interceptor.

Comment: @ave Thank you a lot. AbstractRoutingDataSource apparently seems to be a better way to implement sharding. I'll give it a try.